# Using PHP/mySQL with google maps then add geocoding.. And geocoding not work

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I am interested in Google Maps. I am using [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) for my website because I want store some places in a database. It works well (of course, because I just copied without modifying the given code).

But, after visiting [this site](http://ctrlq.org/maps/address/) I want to geocode the maps so that when the visitor types the name of a street the map will point center on this street in the map.

Can you help me?

Comment: use http://gmap3.net/ he manages the geolocation

Comment: What is what you've tried?  Please either (preferably) post a link to your map where you tried to add geocoding and failed; or enough code that the problem can be reproduced (that limits the people able to help as not everyone is going to setup a complete store locator just to help you.

Comment: Sorry,, It is what i've tried:
i've tried to input codeAddress function that i got from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding to phpsqlajax_map_v3.html at https://developers.google.com /maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.

And then add this code to <body></body> 
----------------------------
<div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
    <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
----------------------------

But the geocode doesn't work

There is limited space in this comment box.. so i can't write the whole code..

Comment: @geocodezip: this is the link to my map [link](http://ikkat.net).

Answer (score 0):

I get a javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'geocode' of undefined

You never create a [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder) object, add 
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

and change:

```
    geocoder.geocode( { 'addressgeoc': addressgeoc}, function(results, status) {
```

to:

```
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addressgeoc}, function(results, status) {
```

as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderRequest)

[Working Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/ikkat_net_geocoderA.html)

On your map, I still get two javsscript errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  http://ikkat.net/:71
Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined http://ikkat.net/:119
```

Please compare your code to my working example

Comment: Thanks for your response..
i've added add geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); and change addressgeoc tp address.. but the script stil not work.. is there anything that i missing?

Comment: Fix the javascript errors.  You probably also need to give the map a height and a width, see [this page (Part 20 Using a percentage height for the map div)](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm) from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial (the concepts of dealing with percentage sized maps don't depend on the version).

Comment: also make your mapgeoc variable global (by removing the "var" in front of this line in the load function: var mapgeoc = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') , {

Comment: I use this site: http://ctrlq.org/maps/address/.. This is not the example that i want, because this map do not use php/mysql to store the places. I do use php/mysql, but i want my site have the search feature like site above.
I just find another tutorial.. still try to follow the instruction.. (https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)

Comment: Thanks for your responses. @geocodezip , you are awesome, I have seen your example link, it works well. Thanks for your help. :)
I will compare and fix my code, and get back to show you the result.